# error with git clone : SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol

Tags: eclipse, git, cmd, gitlab, git-bash

I try to clone repository from gitlab,

it giving this error

fatal: unable to access 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX': error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol

I tried all kind of possibilities like uninstall git,  registry clean, please help on this issue.

Comment: git-cli? windows? linux? eclipse? What are you actually using?

Comment: @firelynx I am using Windows. I tried in all the tools like cmd, eclipse, intelij , and webstom all giving different error. but another machine it working fine with the same login. cmd and intelij gives the above error.

Comment: If you are on windows, why are you not using git bash?

Comment: hi @rogue_js I tried using gitbash also. there also same error.